# Support to ISO-8859-1 on Mkdocs

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I'm using Mkdocs to build my project documentation, but when I try to use `mkdocs serve` or `mkdocs build` i'm getting encoding errors on my `index.md` file.

There is a way to change supported encoding?

Comment: This question needs updates from the author e.g. an excerpt with the essential parts of the error logging. Have a look at https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/2491 too.